# Airflow drops database on reboot (docker)

Tags: airflow

So im trying to setup airflow working on docker and im facing a problem that whenever i reboot airflow container, it recreates the postgres database and drops all the data in there.

Ive set up at environment variable for SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN to a connection string to postgres but it doesnt seem to help.

Any ideas how i could make it retain all the data?

Comment: What is your docker run command? What command do you use to "reboot" the container?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting the solution for the problem now:

I was using docker image for Airflow maintained by Puckel as it seemed to be quite popular. It doesnt seem to be maintained anymore as there is over 100 issues and quite alot pull requests waiting and nothing has happened in past 6 months.

2 things that I recommend doing if you decide to go with Puckel's image of Airflow:

1. Change the postgres backend database to be something newer than the version 9 that is in there by default. Also bind volume to /var/lib/postgresql/data folder to retain all the data (this volume binding didnt work with the version 9 for some reason, I didnt dig any deeper to it).
2. Also bind the entrypoint.sh file to root folder of you docker container and almost at the very bottom change the "initdb" command to "upgradedb". This way you shouldnt have any trouble with the setup.